# LabelEncoding selected columns in a Dataframe using for loop

Tags: python

I have certain columns in my dataset that are "object" type, so first I found them and now I want to transform from categorical to numerical data.
How can I do it in multiple columns using a for loop? I've been struggling with it. I don't want to repeat code.

I've been trying this, but it doesn't work

```
for column in object_columns:
    df.loc[:,column] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df.loc[:,column])
```

Answer (score 6):

### LabelEncoding your features is a bad practice

You should avoid using `LabelEncoder` to encode your input features! Don't believe me? Here's what scikit-learn's [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) for `LabelEncoder` says:

> This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. `y`, and not the input `X`.

That's why it's called **Label**Encoding.

#### Why you shouldn't use `LabelEncoder` to encode features.

This encoder simply makes a mapping of a feature's unique values to integers. For example, let's say we want to encode a feature called *shirt color*, which represents the color of the shirt someone's wearing. This feature has values `['red', 'green', 'blue', ...]`. If you encode these into integers, i.e. `[1, 2, 3, ...]`, you might confuse your model by because you have now given relationships to these values that **don't exist** in the real world, e.g. `red < greed < blue` or `red + green = blue`. This type of feature is called **nominal** and preferably should be [one-hot encoded](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).

There are features however, where you might want to map their values to integers. These are called **ordinal**. For example, the feature *rating*, which has values `['bad', 'good', 'excellent', ...]`. By mapping these to integers you actually preserve the relationsips these values hold in the real world, e.g. `bad < good < excellent`. There is a catch to this however, in order to do the above, you need to map each value with a specific integer (e.g. we can't map `'good' -> 1, 'bad' -> 2, 'excellent' -> 3`, because that doesn't preserve the real-world relationship of these values). The computer **doesn't know which number to map to each value**, though, so if you use `LabelEncoder` even on ordinal variables, it most likely won't generate the correct encoding.

#### How to properly encode ordinal features

A more proper way of encoding ordinal variables is **manually choosing the mapping**. This requires more work and isn't as elegant as a one-liner that encodes all values, but is **the only correct way**. Let's see how we can do this in pandas.

```py
custom_mapping = {'bad': 1, 'good': 2, 'excellent': 3}


df['rating'] = df['rating'].map(custom_mapping)
```

Obviously this needs to be done for each ordinal feature.

---

At this point I think it's clear that I **strongly recommend** against using `LabelEncoder`, but if you still want to do it at least do it correctly.

### If you still want to use LabelEncoding

While both answers by @ggordon and @Anan Srivastava will do what you want, they don't have much value in practice. The problem isthat by not bounding the fitted `LabelEncoder` to a variable, you are **loosing the mapping** from categories to numbers. If you want to predict on future data, you won't know which number to encode each category with.

#### Expanding upon @ggordon's answer

```py
columns_to_be_encoded = [...]  # list of column names you want encoded

# Instantiate the encoders
encoders = {column: LabelEncoder() for column in columns_to_be_encoded}

for column in columns_to_be_encoded:
    df[column] = encoders[column].fit_transform(df[column])
```

This way you have a dictionary of fitted encoders so that you can reuse the same encoding if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @Djib2011: `LabelEncoder` is for the targets/labels, not for other data columns.  Also, I agree that generally you don't want an ordinal encoding, when one-hot is more faithful to the original data.

But, if you do want to ordinal encode, there's a better way: [`OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html).  And if you want it to only apply to certain columns, you can use [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html), e.g.

```
encoder = ColumnTransformer(
              transformers=[('ord_enc', OrdinalEncoder(), object_columns)],
              remainder='passthrough'
              )
df_enc = encoder.fit_transform(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
for column in object_columns:
    df[column] = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[column])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

This will label encode all the columns